# Struts2 token interceptor in annotation

Tags: struts2, annotations, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm using struts 2.3.1 with token interceptor.How can i use token interceptor in annotation(convension) based Action Class.

here is My struts.xml

```
<action name="tokenAction" class="roseindia.action.TokenAction">

 <interceptor-ref name="token" />

 <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>

 <result name="success" >/success.jsp</result>

 <result name="invalid.token">/index.jsp</result>
```

can any one please tell annotation based for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like this is fairly clear in the documentation [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-InterceptorRefannotation), you need to do this:

```
package com.example.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport; 
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Actions;

@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef("token"),
    @InterceptorRef("basicStack")
})
@Results({
    @Result(name="success", location="/success.jsp")
    @Result(name="invalid.token", location="/index.jsp")
})
public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {
  @Action(interceptorRefs={
      @InterceptorRef("token"),
      @InterceptorRef("basicStack")
  })
  public String myActionMethod() {
    //do stuff
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Comment: Added then to the example.

Comment: OK thanks.but token Interceptor in above example is invoke entire actions for that action class.how can i invoke token interceptor for a particular action.

Comment: Edited to provide an example.

Comment: Note that having InterceptorRef defined on the class (or abstract super class) will override the method level ones defined. Not exactly how I would want it - I'd want the class level InterceptorRef on abstract class to act as the general stack, then at the method level to override that (more specific). So I removed from abstract class and just defined it on *all* my @Actions at the method level.