# How to implement form resubmission in struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

any one help me to implement token for avoid resubmission problem in struts 2 step by step

action coding

```
public String enquiry_process()
{


    qty=new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
    matcd=new ArrayList<Integer>();




            purchaseRequisitionDets=procurementService.getPurchaseDet();


            for(int i=0;i<orderCreationBean.getChk_no().length;i++)
            {

                Integer chkno=new Integer(i);
                chkno=orderCreationBean.getChk_no()[i];
                for(PurchaseRequisitionDet purchaseRDet:purchaseRequisitionDets)
                {
                    if(purchaseRDet.getPurch_req_no().equals(chkno))
                    {
                        PurchaseRequisitionDet  objPurchaseRequisitionDet =new PurchaseRequisitionDet();
                        objPurchaseRequisitionDet.setQty(purchaseRDet.getQty());
                        objPurchaseRequisitionDet.setMat_cd(purchaseRDet.getMat_cd());
                        objPurchaseRequisitionDet.setUnit(purchaseRDet.getUnit());
                        objPurchaseRequisitionDet.setUnit_price(purchaseRDet.getUnit_price());
                        objPurchaseRequisitionDet.setTotal(purchaseRDet.getTotal());
                        objprbeanarrays.add(objPurchaseRequisitionDet);
                    }
                }
            }

            HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
            Integer id = (Integer) session.getAttribute("userId");

            procurementService.saveenqdet(enquiryBean.getRef_no(),objprbeanarrays,orderCreationBean,id);



            enquiryHeaderdets=procurementService.getenqhdr();
            for(EnquiryHeaderdet headerdet:enquiryHeaderdets)
            {
                if(headerdet.getRef_no().equals(enquiryBean.getRef_no()))
                {
                Long enq_no=headerdet.getEnq_no();
                qty=procurementService.createenq(enq_no);
                matcd=procurementService.getmatcd(enq_no);

                }
            }
            Long enqno=enquiryBean.getRef_no();

            for(int i=0;i<qty.size();i++)
            {   
                enquiryBean=new EnquiryBean();
                enquiryBean.setQty(qty.get(i).doubleValue());
                enquiryBean.setMat_cd(matcd.get(i));
                MaterialMaster mMaster=procurementService.getMaterial(matcd.get(i));
                enquiryBean.setMat_desc(mMaster.getMat_name());
                enquiryBeans.add(enquiryBean);

            }

            for(EnquiryHeaderdet headerdet:enquiryHeaderdets)
            {
                enquiryBean2=new EnquiryBean();
                if(headerdet.getRef_no().equals(enqno))
                {
                    enquiryBean2.setEnq_no(headerdet.getEnq_no());
                    break;
                }

            }

            orderCreationBean=new OrderCreationBean();
            enquiryBean=new EnquiryBean();
            objprbeanarrays=new ArrayList<PurchaseRequisitionDet>();


    return "success";

}
```

struts.xml

```
    <result name="success">/pages/procurement/EnquiryProcess.jsp</result>

    </action>
```

```
    <result name="success">/pages/procurement/EnquiryDetails.jsp</result>


</action>
```

when i refresh this EnquiryDetails.jsp its perform before page(EnquiryProcess.jsp) i am submit some one value that again resubmit and save in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1 :** put result for invalid token for that action in `struts.xml`

```
 <result name="invalid.token">somePage.jsp</result>
```

Note: Do not forget to add token interceptor in action

```
<action name="tokenAction" class="yourPackageName.yourActionClass">
     <interceptor-ref name="token"></interceptor-ref>
        <!--
        OR <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"></interceptor-ref>
         -->
     <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
     <result name="success" >/success.jsp</result>
     <result name="invalid.token">/invalid_token.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**Step 2 :** In jsp in form use `<s:token />`

```
<s:form action="tokenAction" method="post">
   <s:token />
   ....//other form elements
</s:form>
```

**Step 3 :** in `invalid_token.jsp`

```
<html>
<body>
   Please do not resubmit. Resubmission is banned on this site.
</body>
</html>
```

Read this example carefully to understand [token ins struts2](http://www.journaldev.com/2281/struts2-token-interceptor-to-handle-double-form-submission-problem). You can also find many tutorials step by step.

**Note :** *You can also do the same using Annotations* [Check this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14977330/1459174)

Comment: thanks for your valuable solution i did one mistake in jsp i put </s:token> after other elements now its working.

Comment: I think you can put it anywhere in the form, but the problem is with the syntax of `<s:token />` you used...

Comment: hi i have another doubt if i press back (page back) its save again

Comment: After save try to redirect to anothrt page, not forward. Use redirect.

Comment: You can also set HTTP Header values like no-cache,pragma etc. so the page will not be cached in browser.